# Does Windows Firewall have a log?

Tags: windows-vista, router, firewall, port-forwarding, windows-firewall

I am trying to set my router to forward three of my ports for EchoLink. But I'm having trouble with it. I'm Using the PFPortChecker to see if the ports are open, it says they aren't, but to check my firewall logs for their IP address.

Does Windows Vista have firewall logs?

If so, how do I get to them?

I have Windows Firewall turned on.

Comment: Turn off windows firewall, and see if the ports forward, if they do, thats your problem if not, then its still probably your echolink config.

Comment: That's a good idea, @Sickest.  However, I definitely have set the ports and the EchoLink application open at the firewall.  The problem seems most likely to be the router, since I've tried to set the port forwarding accordingly, and am unsure if what I see in the admin page reflects its actual settings.  Looking in the firewall log would tell me if the router passed the UCP message from EchoLink through to the PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you enable logging you can find them at `C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\Firewall`. Read more about it here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947815(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: whoever voted this answer down: why?